Bumping someone else's old question with no answers
I recently had an oddly specific question that happened to be asked on math.stackexchange about 11 years ago, with no answers (Automorphisms of a lattice and changing to a nicer $\mathbb{Z}$-base). Is it acceptable to bump it somehow? Or is it better to re-ask the question?

Have you considered a bounty?

Yes, it is. You can add a bounty, where you offer some of your reputation as a reward to encourage answers and draw attention to the question.
Do not re ask the question, it will just get closed as a duplicate.
